# Efectuar redireccion después de enviar correo en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap, email

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    require 'funcs/conexion.php';
    include 'funcs/funcs.php';

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }

    $errors = array();

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

        if(!isEmail($email))
        {
            $errors[] = "Debe ingresar un correo electronico valido";
        }

        if(emailExiste($email))
        {           
            $user_id = getValor('id', 'correo', $email);
            $nombre = getValor('nombre', 'correo', $email);

            $token = generaTokenPass($user_id);

            $url = 'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/u/login/cambia_pass.php?user_id='.$user_id.'&token='.$token;

            $asunto = 'Recuperar Password - Sistema de Usuarios';
            $cuerpo = "Hola $nombre: <br/><br/>Se ha solicitado un reinicio de contrase&ntilde;a. <br/><br/>Para restaurar la contrase&ntilde;a, visita la siguiente direcci&oacute;n: <a href='$url'>$url</a>";

            if(enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo)){
                //$resultado = "<div class='alert alert-primary' role='alert'>Hemos enviado un correo electronico a las direcion <b> $email </b> con los pasos para restablecer tu password.<br><a class='alert-link' href='index.php' >Iniciar Sesion</a></div>";
            echo "<script language='JavaScript'>"; 
            echo "location = 'correoenviado.php'"; 
            echo "</script>"; 
            //exit;
            }
            } else {
            $errors[] = "La direccion de correo electronico no existe";
            //$resultado = "<div class='col-11 alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Lo sentimos pero la direcion <b> $email </b> no esta en nuestra base de datos.</div>";

        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Recuperar Password</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">    
            <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
                <div class="panel panel-info" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Recuperar Password</div>
                        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="index.php">Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n</a></div>
                    </div>     

                    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                        <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                        <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email" required>                                        
                            </div>

                            <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                    <button id="btn-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                        No tiene una cuenta! <a href="registro.php">Registrate aquí</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <?php echo resultBlock($errors); ?>  

                        </form>

                    </div>                     
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

En términos generales lo que hace el script es enviar un correo para recuperar una contraseña, todo ocurre menos el mostrar el mensaje de que ya envió el correo.

Yo intenté haciendo una redirección con el script de `javascript`, haciendo un redirección con un `header` y nada; el script envía el correo pero no da el alerta de que ya envió el correo.

¿Donde y cuál es la falla o el error?

Comment: Revisa la consola para ver si arroja error el javascript

Answer (score 1):

Primero te recomiendo que no uses dentro de `PHP` scripts de `JavaScript`(No es una buena practica de programación). Lo recomendable para mostrar al usuario de que algo ha salido bien o no, dependiendo de lo que haya sucedido en la ejecución del `Script` es usar una cadena de texto pero formateada en `JSON` y que la puedas recibir en `JavaScript` para posteriormente mostrarla en un `.alert-danger` o `.alert-success` de `Bootstrap 4`.

Segundo, deberías de usar el modelo de programación mas común para el diseño y desarrollo de plataformas o aplicaciones web `cliente`- `servidor`, que en este caso podría ser:

**CLIENTES**

- JQuery
- Angular
- Ajax
- Vue
- React
- Entre muchos otros, todo depende de gustos.

**SERVIDOR**

- PHP
- Django
- Python
- Etc...

Dicho esto, es una buena practica, porque te permite tener un mayor control de las peticiones que realices a tu servidor y que este mantenga quieto, simplemente esperando a que los clientes le soliciten algo, además de la facilidad de hacerle mantenimiento a tu código.

> **Nota:** Todo esto como muestra de recomendación.

Por lo que procedo a mostrar lo que yo haría:

**PHP**

```
 <?php
     require 'funcs/conexion.php';
     include 'funcs/funcs.php';
     //Declaracion del array para codificar en formato JSON la variable mensaje
     $resultado = array();
     //Objeto convertido a formato UTF8 para insertar o mostrar caracteres especiales en la BD del sistema
     $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

     session_start();

     if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
         header("Location: welcome.php");
     }

     $errors = array();

     if(!empty($_POST))
     {
         $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

         if(!isEmail($email))
         {
             $errors[] = "Debe ingresar un correo electronico valido";
         }

         if(emailExiste($email))
         {           
             $user_id = getValor('id', 'correo', $email);
             $nombre = getValor('nombre', 'correo', $email);

             $token = generaTokenPass($user_id);

             $url = 'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/u/login/cambia_pass.php?user_id='.$user_id.'&token='.$token;

             $asunto = 'Recuperar Password - Sistema de Usuarios';
             $cuerpo = "Hola $nombre: <br/><br/>Se ha solicitado un reinicio de contrase&ntilde;a. <br/><br/>Para restaurar la contrase&ntilde;a, visita la siguiente direcci&oacute;n: <a href='$url'>$url</a>";

             if(enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo))
             {
               $resultado['mensaje'] = "Hemos enviado un correo electronico a la dirección " .  $email . " con los pasos para restablecer tu contraseña...";
             }
          } 
          else 
          {
            $resultado['mensaje'] = "La dirección de correo electrónico no existe, por favor verifica tu cuenta.";
          }
        //Imprimimos el resultado del mensaje...
         echo json_encode($resultado);
     }
 ?>
```

**Cliente**

Recibes el dato o resultado de la variable mensaje desde el cliente y posteriormente la incluyes o muestras en tu vista HTML.

Comment: Gracias, estoy utilizando `<?php echo resultBlock($resultado); ?>` para mostrar el mensaje y sigue pasando lo mismo, si el correo es errado muestra el mensaje de error, peo si logra enviar el correo no lo indica, solo refresca esa pag y no da ningun mensaje al usuario..!